# What is the significance of // in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I noticed that in bash/zsh if I `cd //` it puts me in a directory with the name '//' - pwd shows that as well as my prompt.

If I use more than two slashes like `cd ///` etc it just puts me in /.

Is there a significance to the directory // in bash?

Comment: Pretty related: [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12283/40596)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The POSIX standard tells `//` might be interpreted a specific way by a conformant operating system, while `///` is equivalent to `/`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12

> If a pathname begins with two successive  characters, the first component following the leading  characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading  characters shall be treated as a single  character.

That's the reason why `bash` is keeping `//` unchanged just in case the underlying OS implements this special meaning.

Comment: I see this even works with `cd //opt/foo`. According to `pwd`, the current directory is `//opt/foo`. I don't see this with Kornshell or Zsh though.

Comment: Ah! I see this is specifically set for running Bash on a PC (such as through Cygwin) where `//foo/bar` is a shared remote directory and not merely a local directory `/foo/bar`.

Comment: @DavidW. more generally for network based file systems that were/are using //host/directory to prefix remote shares. I guess that POSIX detail predates bash/cygwin.

Comment: @jillagre - I wonder why wasn't this a feature of Kornshell which preceded Bash and which became the basis of the POSIX shell standard.

Comment: @DavidW. Interesting comment. My understanding is `ksh` "knows" the system you are running doesn't handle specially a leading `//` so it canonicalize it as a single slash. As far as I know, should you were running on a POSIX conforming OS implementing that specific feature, `getconf PATH_LEADING_SLASHES` would return 1 and `ksh` would preserve the leading slashes. I have no such OS to verify so I'm sticking to analyzing `ksh93` source code and its documentation.